# How to remove residual patterns from GAM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, poisson-distribution, residuals, generalized-additive-model

My data is modelling the proportion of 'foraging' clicks vs overall clicks in a 30 minute interval using GAMs. I have multiple explanatory variables and factors.

I have tried including all my variables in the model with a) a binomial distribution as is suggested for rates, b) a Poisson distribution using buzz percentage (instead of proportion) (with  `link="log"`), c) quasipoisson, and d) a negative binomial.

The binomial model showed patterns in residuals

The Poisson model showed less patterns but clumping of residuals

The overdispersion parameter for the Poisson model (+20) suggested the use of the negative binomial model

The negative binomial showed patterns and clumping in the residuals....

There also seems to be some bimodality in the histogram of residuals..

Seemingly the 'best' model so far for removing residual clumping was a gam with a sqrt transformed response, however the overdispersion value here is very high and the residuals are still unevenly spread.

The diagnostic images attached are for the sqrt poisson

(code below)

```
gam(sqrt(datawidecheck$buzz_prop1)~ 

   s(datawidecheck$Dist_coast_spec,k=10, bs="cr") + 

   s(datawidecheck$month_of_year, k=8, bs="cc") + 

   s(datawidecheck$hour_of_day, bs="cc", k=20) + 

   s(datawidecheck$HW_full, bs="cc", k=10) +

   datawidecheck$data_year + datawidecheck$var, 

   family=poisson(link="identity"))
```

I have also tried:

other response variable transformations i.e log

including model interactions

I'm not sure what else I can do to try and fix this problem?

[image]